# Can simple recurrent neural networks be remedied with higher precision floating point numbers?

Tags: machine-learning

I am of the understanding that tradition "simple" recurrent neural networks have the problem of "losing error" after a lot of time steps. But is this some kind of deficiency of the math, or the machines the RNN's are running on? If it's just the machines, couldn't you use something like an arbitrary precision float and store all the information "exactly"? (Then, even if you go out some ludicrous amount of time steps, you would presumably be able to calculate the gradient.)

Comment: So you meant a recurrent neural network ran for $T$ timesteps and the error is a function of the value of the output neurons at the last timestep ? Then this is the same [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) as for NN with many layers, and float/double precision isn't the point.

Comment: What do you mean by "losing error" and why is it a problem?  I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about.